# Delay android PlusClient login request

Tags: android, google-plus-one, google-play-services

I am trying to implement the new PlayServices API within my android application to use a +1 button.

I have it working nicely, all the expected functionality is there. However it has one rather annoying feature (seriously google!). When you instance the plusclient:

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient(this, this, this, Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE);
```

Your user is presented with a "Pick your account" dialog (if they have more than one account) followed by a "grant access" dialog. I understand the need for these steps, however they really get in the way of the user experience!

My initial activity (post splash screen) now has the +1 button, which means that you have to instance the PlusClient. Doing so in the onCreate() method (as google suggests) means that my user is given the "authorisation" screen before they even know what is going on!

What I want to do it delay that untill they actually click the +1 button. That way they will know why they are being asked to authorise access to their account!

Any ideas? I have tried using an onClick listener on the +1 button to instance but it didn't work.

Comment: As the `PlusClient` is first required when you call `PlusOneButton.initialize()`, you maybe could instantiate the `PlusOneButton` and add it you your layout, add an `OnClickListener` to the Button and call `initialize` when the Button is clicked the first time. I haven't tried this however.

Comment: I did try an onClickListner (as mentioned) and didn't get very far. I think that the plusclient must take control of the "button" (not a real button) and rebind any listeners. It also seems that Google isn't letting developers publish using this api yet!

Comment: Hm, as a workaround, you could have a dummy +1 button (greyed out or something) and on click initialize the `PlusClient` and replace it with the real +1 button.

Comment: That was going to be my next try tonight. Will let you know!

Comment: Good news: Apps using Google Play Services can [now be published](https://plus.google.com/u/0/108967384991768947849/posts/6zynpohYP6c).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to remove the `Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE` for the desired behavior. The documentation from Google+ has been updated to reflect this.

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient(this, this, this);
```